# URL redirect with GAE/J

Tags: java, google-app-engine

My Java app hosted on GAE works fine with the following urls

> www.myappid.appspot.com
>
> www.myappid.appspot.com/home
>
> www.mydomain.com/home

but would not work for

> www.mydomain.com

It takes me to "site under construction" page

I have a welcome jsp in app which redirects to current URL+"/home"

www.mydomain.com should have ideally redirected to www.mydomain.com/home and rendered the page - `Plz note that www.mydomain.com/home works when i deep dive`

I have the necessary DNS changes to route www subdomain to cname ghs.google.com and added www.mydomain.com as web address in the admin page of my business app.

Also none of the pages are secured - changed app.yaml to reflect the same.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please let me know the reason for down vote!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seems to work fine now with no change in code. Thanks for the help.